Overfull hbox when using subequations and empheq inside a minipage
I got 8 warnings of bad boxes, "Overfull \hbox (1.66663pt too wide)", when I compile the following code. When I use align instead of empheq, the bad boxes don't occur. What could be the problem?
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Rotations in the plane}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.34\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \text{(FIGURE HERE)}\\
  \hspace{115pt}
\end{figure}  
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.64\textwidth}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item In an orthogonal coordinate system \( Oxy \), rotating a point \( P = (x, y) \) by an angle \( \theta \) around the origin, with \( r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \), \( x = r \cos \alpha \), and \( y = r \sin \alpha \), results in the point \( P' = (x', y') \) such that
        \[  \begin{aligned}
              x' &= r\cos(\alpha+\theta) = r \cos \alpha \cos \theta - r \sin \alpha \sin \theta,\\
              y' &= r\sin(\alpha+\theta) = r \sin \alpha \cos \theta + r \sin \theta \cos \alpha;\\
            \end{aligned}\]
        that is,
        \begin{subequations}
        \label{E:RotPlanCoordOrt}
          \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace\,]{align}
            x' &= x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta, \label{E:RotPlanCoordOrtox}\\
            y' &= x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta. \label{E:RotPlanCoordOrtoy}
          \end{empheq}
        \end{subequations}
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



It seems that empheq doesn't wok well in beamer. If you can leave without labeling of equation in empheq, warnings will disappear. To me this is bug. However, this warnings doesn't harm your slide formatting.

It seems a bug and the overfull is caused by the \label.
I can propose a workaround, that is, to put the \label in a zero width box.
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage{empheq}

\newcommand{\hacklabel}[1]{\makebox[0pt]{\label{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Rotations in the plane}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.35\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item
  \begin{subequations}\label{E:RotPlanCoordOrt}\hfuzz=2pt
  In an orthogonal coordinate system \( Oxy \), rotating a point 
  \( P = (x, y) \) by an angle \( \theta \) around the origin,
  with \( r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \), \( x = r \cos \alpha \), and
  \( y = r \sin \alpha \), results in the point \( P' = (x', y') \)
  such that
  \[
  \begin{aligned}
    x' &= r\cos(\alpha+\theta) = r \cos \alpha \cos \theta - r \sin \alpha \sin \theta,\\
    y' &= r\sin(\alpha+\theta) = r \sin \alpha \cos \theta + r \sin \theta \cos \alpha;\\
  \end{aligned}
  \]
  that is,
    \begin{empheq}[left={\empheqlbrace\,}]{align}
      x' &= x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta,\hacklabel{E:RotPlanCoordOrtox}\\
      y' &= x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta.\hacklabel{E:RotPlanCoordOrtoy}
    \end{empheq}
  \end{subequations}
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

Note that I used columns rather than minipage. There's no law prescribing that \includegraphics should go inside figure.


Right, I tested it, and it worked. Thank you. About your comment "There's no law prescribing that \includegraphics should go inside figure.", I know it, but I want the figure environment, because I need figure numbering.

@JoãoAlvesJr. I believe that in a presentation there should be no numbering at all. The audience will never remember them. And I also believe that handing out slides is bad habit: slides may be useful for a lecture, but they're no substitute for lecture notes or a textbook. Anyway, columns is the right tool.

The thing is, I want to prepare a book, and I also need to prepare slides for lectures, and the latter goal is more urgent. I don't have time to prepare both things separately, so I prepare the slides first, and later I will turn it into a book. Also, numbering the figures is useful for reference when students have a question or suggestion for corrections. But I do not depend on these numberings when I am presenting: I repeat figures and other floating elements whenever convenient. About columns: I'll try this from now on.
